# Folders displaying in orange color in python 3, pycharm

Tags: pycharm, basic

Can somebody point me in the right direction on this? I just can't find any ressources on why a folder will display in orange as if it was not active. I can't import modules from there since its not active and i can't activate it at all and i don't know where to look lol.

I linked a screenshot so people could see what i'm talking about

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyM1r.png)

Comment: I had the same problem which was solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293073/13590821

Comment: I had the same problem which was solved by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293073/13590821

Answer (score 4):

The directory is marked as excluded. Right-click on the directory in the project tree -> Mark Directory as ... -> Excluded.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend for your answer. So i tried your solution but it seems that the option "mark directory as..." doesn't exist on the orange directory. I also tried every folder that were containing the orange file up to the first folder, which is named "External libraries".
One interresting thing is that I also tried to right click on one of the folders i personnally created and the option was there though!

Comment: I wish i could post a second picture but i don't see how to do that

Comment: I see, is this excluded folder shown in **Settings | Project ... | Project Structure**?

Comment: YES, allright my friend thanks for your answer. It allowed me to find what was the solution!!

Comment: I went to "settings --- project --- project structure" And then i added the orange file using the "+ add content root" located in the top right corner of the "settings"  window.
My only question would be why did my newly created project not include this folder as it included the other ones in the "lib" folder (like html, http, adlelib, importlib etc etc) So basically all the files were included but the one i needed (the one in which pip download all the content...)

Thx a lot anyway man, programming is such a pain sometimes and the feeling is also so great when we solve a problem somehow :P